# Filter options item order - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

I want to change the order of the filters in the category view. 
A the moment color is the first filter. I want another filter to be the first.

So I tried to set the position of the attribute "Color" in the Attributeset behind some others but nothing has changed in the frontend.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set attribute position from Adminpanel.

> Stores -> Attributes -> Product

Select Attribute and go to tabs **`Storefront Properties`**,

Set **Position** field for each attibutes.

Clear cache.

Comment: field is disabled form me. why?

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya Is there any way to do it programatically as I have lot of attibutes to sort.