# Magento2 - Reorder options inside layered filter

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, magento2.2.6

I'm quite new to Magento so maybe this is a stupid question.

I have some filters set up in the layer navigation, one of them is the size of the products we're selling.

I'd like to know if it's possible to reorder the options inside that size filter because now they are appearing in alphabetic order but I'd like to display them something like: XS-S-M-L-XL. Below image is a screenshot of how they are displaing right now.

[image: Current display status]

I've read a lot of questions and posts but they are only to rearrange the entire filters on the layered navigation, not the options inside them.

Hope I've been clear enough for you to understand. If any further details are needed just let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please follow this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140927/filter-options-item-order-magento-2

Comment: @nishu That is not what I asked for. The question you linked is to change the order of the entire filters, not just the options inside them. But thank you anyways!

Comment: Hey can you drag and drop the options to some other place in your size attribute in admin and save the attribute, fronted layered navigation option sequence will change accordingly.

Comment: @GuillermoG have you try my answer?

Comment: @nishu That was it! The options didn't have that thing that lets you drag them but they are still draggable. Write a propper answer, if you want, and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @GuillermoG Thanks!!  Glad it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rearrange Size attribute options

In the admin, edit the attribute and in the options section of attribute. try to drag and drop the option to required place and save the attribute.

Clear cache and it will work on the frontend.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

To rearrange **Size** Attribute value in layered navigation you have to override below core file.

> vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml

The **renderer.phtml** file is responsible for display HTML for attribute in layerd navigation.

In **renderer.phtml** the file you can see they apply switch case `(switch ($swatchData['swatches'][$option]['type'])` method to display attribute like size, color etc..

In the switch case function you need to look in to **case '0':** because **Size** attribute type is executed in **case '0':**

So you have to sort this code `($swatchData['swatches'][$option]['value'])` using php function  or any other method to display size attrinute value in `XS-S-M-L-XL`

To override template file see [How to override phtml file in magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sure it do the trick, but the answer I was looking for is Nishu's answer. Thank you anyways!!

Comment: Great!! it's so easy then why should go for customization. Good answer @nishu :)